# ListView : In simple listview, while changing the background color of the view in listview then it also changes below while scrolling

Tags: android

this is my code. here the background color of selected row is changing. but after scrolling the bachground color of not selected view is also changed.i want to prevent this problem. any help?

```
  public class ListDemoActivity extends ListActivity {
         String[] names = {
                    "Dwight",
                    "Kennedy",
                    "Johnson",
                    "Richard",
                    "Gerald",
                    "Jimmy",
                    "Ronald",
                    "George",
                    "Bill",
                    "B. Bush",
                    "Rana"
            };
         View view;
         int posn = -1;
        @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.main);
            setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, names));
        }
        @Override
        protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {



    Log.i("Log", "Clicked posn"+position);
    Log.i("Log", "id is: "+id);
    if(posn == -1)
    {
        v.setBackgroundResource(R.color.blue);
    //  l.getChildAt(position).setBackgroundResource(R.color.blue);
        view = v;
        posn = position;    
    }
    else if (posn == position)
    {
        v.setBackgroundResource(R.color.blue);
        //l.getChildAt(position).setBackgroundResource(R.color.blue);
    }
    else
    {
        Log.i("Log", "Count of child:  "+l.getChildCount());
    //  View view = l.getChildAt(posn);
    //  Log.i("Log", "Position: "+view.)
        //view.setBackgroundResource(R.color.black);

        //view = l.getChildAt(position);
        //view.setBackgroundResource(R.color.blue);

        view.setBackgroundResource(R.color.black);
        v.setBackgroundResource(R.color.blue);
        view = v;
        posn = position;
    }
    }
}
```

Comment: Explain your problem

Comment: What is the feature you are trying to implement. What is the end result you want with this code?

Comment: i am changing the background color of selected row and its done. the problem is that when i select the first row and scroll the list then the background color of below appeared row is automatically changed. i want to prevent that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It happens because the ListView reuses its cells through its adapter; when a cell is scrolled out of view, it gets put on the bottom, so if you color it blue and scroll it, it will appear below.

You can write a simple custom adapter in which you keep track of which cells you want colored, and color accordingly in the [`getView(..)`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Adapter.html#getView%28int,%20android.view.View,%20android.view.ViewGroup%29) method you'll have to override. See also [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wDBM6wVEO70&list=PL734A052F802C96B9&index=23&feature=plpp_video) on ListViews.